# Redirect route with input

Tags: php, laravel-5

Consider this scenario, I have the following pair of routes:

```
Route::post('cart/update', ['uses' => 'CartController@update', 'as' => 'cart.update']);
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'order/checkout', ['uses' => 'OrderController@checkout', 'as' => 'order.checkout']);
```

In the `cart.update` route, if I do this:

```
return Redirect::route('order.checkout')->withInput();
```

And then I use `dd(Input::all())` at `order.checkout`, I receive an empty array.

However, instead If I am to use `dd(Input::old())`, then I receive the array with the input values I was expecting.

**Is it supposed to behave like that?**

**Shouldn't I properly receive `Input::all()` at `order.checkout` route?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input

> You may need to keep input from one request until the next request.
>   For example, you may need to re-populate a form after checking it for
>   validation errors.
>
> Since you often will want to flash input in association with a
>   redirect to the previous page, you may easily chain input flashing
>   onto a redirect.

So yes, the behavior is correct. You're supposed to use Input::old() to potentially repopulate forms that may have not passed validation, for example.